# Alternative to PDFLib

Tags: pdf

I would like to know if there are alternatives to PDFLib for use with Genexus 9; either free or low cost as we are most likely not going to be authorized to drop 1200 Dollars for the license.

We use PDFLib to generate PDF files from Genexus reports, currently we have been running "PDFlib-8.0.6-COM" on the production server but no one seems to know if it's using a bought license or not.